# DataTable sorting using Jquery based on value

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, datatable

I have a datable and with column values start from 0 to 100.  My sorting is working fine with below code.

it shows the result from 0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10.. 99,100.  so on

```
jQuery('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
        "scrollX": true
    }).columns(1).order('asc').draw();
```

I want need to see the result starting from 1,2,3,4,6, ......99,100,0. IS there is any way to achieve this within datatable

Comment: Do you want to modify your sorting dynamically or in your jQuery DataTable's initialization?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want a custom ordering method, but the `.order()` method ([Datatables docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order())) does not allow this (see this [Datatables forum thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32899/override-order-function) - *"If you want to control the ordering yourself you would need to use a plug-in ordering method."*)

So, these links could be useful to create a custom ordering method:

- [Datatables: Ordering plug-in development](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/sorting) - example provided
- or maybe: [Sorting plug-ins](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/) - example provided
- also this forum thread on [Custom sorting](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26301/custom-sorting-disabling-sorting-per-column#Comment_71943)